# Double to string with arduino::String prints format instead of value?

Tags: string, arduino, double, precision, arduino-c++

I've been experiencing this in a project where I'm doing a large volume of double and float to string conversions, but I've whittled it down to something very small that showcases the problem.

```
void setup() {
  double num = 123456789.12;
  String numString = String(num);
  Serial.print("Num String: ");
  Serial.println(numString.c_str());
}

// outputs
// Num String: %4.2f
```

I'm sure someone will look at this and say, of course, this is expected behavior! But I'm really struggling to understand why. I can't for the life of me get a properly formatted, with precision, double or float printed in logging output with Serial.print. I've tried this with other string conversion techniques such as:

```
template <typename T>
std::string MyStringUtil::ToStringWithPrecision(const T a_value, const int n)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    stream << std::fixed << std::setprecision(n) << a_value;
    return stream.str();
}
```

But this also returns the same thing, what I think is a format string, but I could be wrong.

Can anyone explain the mechanics of what's leading to this output? For context this is being run on a Sparkfun Redboard Nano.

EDIT:

```
void setup() {
  double num = 123456789.12;
  String numString = String(num);
  Serial.print("Num String: ");
  Serial.print(num);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.println(numString);
}

// outputs
// Num String: 123456789.12 | %4.2f
```

For added context, this is all being run using the Arduino IDE, output is being read via the Serial Monitor directly from a USB connected Redboard Nano at 9600 baud.

Comment: Two (unrelated) things: First do `String numString(num);` instead, even if the compiler will likely optimize your copy-initialization to direct initialization you might as well do it yourself. Secondly, no need to do `c_str()` as I remember. `Serial.println(numString)` should be enough.

Comment: As for your problem, except the missing serial port setup it should work (assuming that the receiving serial port is set up in the exact same way as your Arduino serial port default configuration). What you're seeing is *not* expected behavior. So the questions for you now becomes: How do you set up your serial ports, both on the Arduino and on the receiving site? And what are you doing on the receiving side, how do you receive the string and how do you display it? Please **[edit]** your question to give us those details.

Comment: Ah I see, roger that. Also updated the post with a sanity check.

Comment: Ok, I'm really glad I'm not just insane. Or at least not because of this. I'm running this on a SparkFun Redboard Nano through the Arduino IDE. Just pushing it right to the redboard and then the output I've posted is straight from the serial monitor. It's all running on defaults, talking to the redboard at 9600 baud.